# access the function of my library

Tags: php, codeigniter

I encounter this error when I try to access the function of my library:
A PHP Error was encountered

> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: ControllerUser::$alertClasse
>
> Filename: controllers/ControllerUser.php
>
> Line Number: 183
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File:
>   C:\wamp64\www\logistock\application\controllers\ControllerUser.php
>   Line: 183 Function: _error_handler
>
> File:
>   C:\wamp64\www\logistock\application\controllers\ControllerUser.php
>   Line: 22 Function: call_user_func_array
>
> File: C:\wamp64\www\logistock\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

This is my library:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class AlertClasse
{
    protected $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->model('AlerteModel');

    }

    public function stockSeuil()
    {
        $query=$this->CI->AlerteModel->getarticles();
        $tabStockSeuil = array();
        foreach($query as $tab)
        {

            if($tab->art_solde<=$tab->seuil_alert_art)
            {
              $article[] = $tab->id_art;
              $article[] = $tab->lib_art;
              $article[] = $tab->art_solde;
              $article[] = $tab->seuil_alert_art;   
              $article[] = $tab->perissable;        
              $tabStockSeuil[] = $article;
              $article = array();
            }
        }
        return $tabStockSeuil;
    }

    public function stockExpire()
    {
        $query=$this->CI->AlerteModel->get_art_lot();
        $tabartexpire = array();
        $datejour = date('d/m/Y');

         $djour = explode("/", $datejour);

        $auj = mktime(00, 00, 00,$djour["1"],$djour["0"],$djour["2"]);


        foreach($query as $tab)
        {

            if($tab->date_expir!=0)
            {

            $datexpiration= $tab->date_expir;  

            if ($auj>=$datexpiration)
            { 
                $id = $tab->id_lot;
                $artexpire[] = $tab->lib_art;
                $artexpire[] = $tab->qte_lot;
                $artexpire[] = $tab->date_enregistrement;
                $artexpire[] = $tab->date_expir;

                $tabartexpire[] =$artexpire;
                $this->articles_model->mis_au_rebut($id);
                $artexpire = array();

            }
        }

            }
          return $tabartexpire;
    } 


    public function ExpireProche()
    {
        $query=$this->CI->AlerteModel->get_art_lot();
        $tabartexpire = array();
        $datejour = date('d/m/Y');

         $djour = explode("/", $datejour);

        $auj =  mktime(00, 00, 00, $djour["1"], $djour["0"], $djour["2"]);

        $nextDat =time() + (5 * 24 * 60 * 60);
        $temp =date('d/m/Y', $nextDat);
        $temp = explode("/", $temp);  

        $nextDate  = mktime(00, 00, 00, $temp["1"],$temp["0"],$temp["2"]);    
        foreach($query as $tab)
        {
            if($tab->date_expir!=0)
            {

            $datexpiration= $tab->date_expir; 



          if (intval($auj)<intval($datexpiration) && intval($nextDate) >= 
        intval($datexpiration))
            { 

                $artexpire[] = $tab->lib_art;
                $artexpire[] = $tab->qte_lot;
                $artexpire[] = $tab->date_enregistrement;
                $artexpire[] = $tab->date_expir;
                // On met ensuite le résultat obtenu dans un tableau 
                $tabartexpire[] =$artexpire;
                $artexpire = array();

         }
        }


            }

            return $tabartexpire;


    }
}
```

and in my controller:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class ControllerUser extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {

        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('alertClasse');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('session');
    }
}
```

here i try to access to the method:

```
public function affichageUser(){
   //error here
    $tabExpirProch = $this->alertClasse->ExpireProche();
    $priv = $this->UserModel->getpriv();
    $this->load->view('users/listUser',['privilege'=>$priv]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is happening because codeigniter cant find the file in your application/libraries folder.

Make sure that the file name of your library's class is "AlertClasse.php"
Because codeigniter states the following rules for Creating Libraries:

> 1. File names must be capitalized. For example: Myclass.php
> 2. Class declarations must be capitalized. For example: class Myclass
> 3. Class names and file names must match.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/creating_libraries.html#storage

Answer (score 0):

You must get access to method of library using name of class:

```
$tabExpirProch = $this->AlertClasse->ExpireProche();
```

Comment: that's what I did

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on my proyect.
I can call every model this way, on CI v3.1.6

Model (only to show a difference):

```
class SomeClass extends CI_Model{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct()
    }
    function someFunction($foo){
        //do something
    }
}
```

In Controller:

```
class SomeController extends CI_Controller{
    function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        //Load model, no problem
        $this->load->model('SomeClass');
        //Load library, no problem
        $this->load->library('MyLibrary');
    }
    function someFunctionToUseModelFunction(){
        $foo = 'Hello my friend';
        //no problem with using the model
        $bar = $this->SomeClass->SomeFunction($foo);
        //library, NOT FOUND
        $a = $this->MyLibrary->someFunctionInLibrary();
    }
}
```

Turns out when i tried with libraries when i nedded to call the functions within the library i could not, checked the names, file name, where i was calling those...nothing.
(Sorry about my english) I "lowercased" the name of the library and i did this

```
function __construct(){
    $this->load->library('MyLibrary');
}

function functionToCallTheLbrary(){
    //this way it has worked for my so far with all the libraries i have
    //lowercase the class name, and call the functions with the names u declare those
    $var = $this->mylibrary->someFunction();
}
```

Hope my answer helps u.